# "for" loop added when I use minus and subtracted when I use plus

Tags: c, loops, cs50

Why when I add 1 in `for loop` in inner loop it's subtract a value and when I write `- 1`it added a value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    //assignment name "height" to data type "integer"
    int height; 
    //сheck that the player has entered height from 1 to 8
    do 
    {
        height = get_int("Height:");
    }
    while (height < 1 || height > 8);
    // print columns according to the number seted by player
    for (int colums = 0; colums < height; colums++)
    {
        printf("#");

        //print rows according to the number seted by player minus one row   
            for (int rows = colums + 1; rows < height; rows++)
            {
                printf("@");
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Height:4    
#@@@
#@@
#@
#
```

[here's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9OXp.png)

Now I've change value from `for(rows = colums + 1;...)` to `for(rows = colums - 1;...)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    //assignment name "height" to data type "integer"
    int height; 
    //сheck that the player has entered height from 1 to 8
    do 
    {
        height = get_int("Height:");
    }
    while (height < 1 || height > 8);
    // print columns according to the number seted by player
    for (int colums = 0; colums < height; colums++)
    {
        printf("#");

        //print rows according to the number seted by player minus one row   
            for (int rows = colums - 1; rows < height; rows++)
            {
                printf("@");
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Height:4
#@@@@@
#@@@@
#@@@
#@@
```

[here's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Mt9.png)

Comment: what happens with the `-1` version when `columns` is 0? Try to perform the loops manually and follow the value of each variable. It is not too hard in your example

Comment: Please paste your code in rather than using pictures. You can and should include your output, too. It's definitely not more comfortable or easier in any way to see an image of your code instead of actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the situation is a loop like this:

```
for (rows = columns + 1; rows < height; rows++) {
     // do something
}
```

I think you're asking why the loop executes fewer times when the loop says `for (rows = columns + 1;...` than when it says `for (rows = columns - 1;...`. The reason is that the first part of a `for` loop is the initial condition; it's where you give `rows` it's starting value. If you *add* 1 to the starting value, and then count *up* to some final value (`height` in this case), then you've *decreased* the difference between the starting value and the final value.

Consider this:

```
height = 3;
for (rows = 1; rows < height; rows++) {...}
```

versus this:

```
height = 3;
for (rows = -1; rows < height; rows++) {...}
```

Which one of those loops do you suppose will execute more times?

Comment: Version with [-1] will have more outputs because it will have more iterations before [row = height].

Thanks for so understandable explanation! It has moved me into the next level ))

Answer (score 1):

When you using,

```
for(int row = column+1; row<height; row++)
```

you are instructing the compiler to run the loop from the initial value of row+1. Hence the for loop is executed one time less.

E.g column=3, row = 3+1 =4 , height = 6 .Then for loop will be executed 2 times, i.e for row = 4 and 5

Similarly

```
for(int row = column-1; row<height; row++)
```

it will be executed for two extra times extra.

E.g column=3, row = 3-1 =2, height = 6 .Then for loop will be executed 3 times, i.e for row = 2,3,4 and 5.